# Laravel undefined method revoke

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am test building an application, using Laravel, Laravel passport and socialite to login and logout users in a vue SPA. No problem to login and create users, it is only when I try to logout users that I get the error: call to undefined method: revoke

This is in Auth\LoginController:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
    return response()->json([
        'message'   =>  'Successfully logged out.'
    ]);
}
```

This is in Api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

This is axios called in vue SPA:

```
logout() {
    axios.post('/api/logout')
    .then(res=>{
        console.log(res.data);
    });
}
```

If revoke works I should get the message for successfully logged out. Any help here is appreciated.

Additional: in my LoginController handleProviderCallback function to handle the socialite logins I have this

```
    auth()->login($user);
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'access_token'  =>  $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type'    =>  'Bearer',
        'expires_at'    =>  Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
```

The outcome is when users click on social logins, it shows the access token. I have always thought laravel_token from cookies is the JWT which Laravel automatically handles. Now I am not very sure. So if with this additional code, the access token is the right way to handle JWT, how do I pass the response into Vue since it is a redirect from socialite, not an Axios request?

After the JWT is tested i can try out on the logout again to see if the JWT is the issue.

Comment: try using ->destroy(); instead of revoke.

Comment: outcome is the same, undefined method destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with the default Auth::logout(). The code for the 'Personal Access Token' is not needed. In the documentation of passport Laravel attaches a JWT in a cookie called laravel_token which passport will check if user is authenticated.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the user has a token ? And are you using the `HasApiTokens` trait in your User model ?

Comment: yes the user model has 'HasApiTokens', and the database has the personal access tokens issued when i login